# How to create an EmailTemplate record with IsBuilderContent field set to TRUE?

Tags: soap-api

I am trying to create an `EmailTemplate` record using the Salesforce SOAP API (the final goal is to mass-automate the re-creation of lightning email templates from one org to another).

I get the following message :

```
Unable to create/update fields: IsBuilderContent. Please check the security settings of this field and verify that it is read/write for your profile or permission set.'
 statusCode='INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE'
```

I can't see that field (`IsBuilderContent`), so I am unable to change its permissions, and I need it to be set to `TRUE` so the newly created Email Template can be edited in Pardot Lightning Builder.

Did anyone manage to do such a thing, or have any insight on how to create such a record?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular field is not [creatable nor updateable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailtemplate.htm?q=emailtemplate)

> IsBuilderContent
>
> Type boolean
>
> Properties: Defaulted on create, Filter, Group, Sort
>
> Description: If the email template was made in Email Template Builder. The default value is false.

AFAIK, you'll need to do these manually

Comment: That is what I was a afraid of. Any chance a tool like Dataloader can by-pass this ?

Comment: nope - DataLoader uses the same API as REST/SOAP clients do

Comment: Thanks for you answers ;) I've seen Email Templates in App Exchange, so I was wondering if packaging could help here.